# Custom Labels in CollectionType field in symfony3

Tags: php, forms, label, symfony

I try to implement custom labels into an collection of form in Symfony3. I have no idea how to solve it. May you help me please?

I have an array of Questions, which i would like to use as label of my form collection.

```
#question for the question Form, this are the question u have to answer
Questions:
   - 'Question 1: Ich habe ziemlich regelmässig Tagträume und Fantasien über Dinge, die mir passieren Könnten'
   - 'Question 2: Ich empfinde warmherzige Gefühle für Leute, denen es weniger gut geht als mir'
   - 'Question 3: Manchmal fällt es mit schwer, die Dinge vom Standpunkt der anderen zu betrachten'
   - 'Question 4: Hin und wieder tun mir Menschne sehr leid, wenn sie Probleme haben'
```

this ist my form contoller:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;
use AppBundle\Controller\Questions;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class PfsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('answers', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => AnswerType::class,
        ));
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\PsychoTest'
        ));
    }
}
```

I made my actually sollution in twig.:

```
{% for answers in form.answers %}
    {{ form_label(answers.name, questions[loop.index0]) }}
    <li>{{ form_row(answers.name) }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

but i would like to put the questions directy to my form....

Thx for your help

Micha

Comment: Please provide Answer and Question entity declaration (to understand where do you keep question text)

Comment: Hi, I think I understand what you need. Question for you: Does the questions need to be a drop down list? If so, maybe adding a EntityType Field to you form is the best solution.

Comment: no, i would like to use the question as a label, but i dont know if this is the best praktice